# Customizing UIView for tableView delegate method

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to create my own custom UIView for the header of a grouped `UITableView`.  This is the code I'm playing with so far:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    Target *aTarget = [targetDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, self.TargetTableView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aTarget.condition];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.TargetTableView.frame.size.width, 200)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
//    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return [headerView autorelease];
}
```

Couple questions.  For my headerView, I wanted the height to be 40, but it looked SO small.  Then I changed it to 60, and I saw it didn't change at all in my `UITableView` (I'm presenting this data in a popover which I don't think should matter).  So I made the height 200 just to see if it would change and the orange view I have is tiny.  Probably only as big as the status bar if that.

Next I have my `UILabel`.  I want it to be somehwat centered in my `UIView`.  When I show it though, it's not even in my `UIView`.  It's on top of my first row of my `UITableView`.  When I initialize it with the `CGRectMake()`, is it setting it in the coordinates of the parent view or something that is shifting it off?  I was trying to create it where I'd want to position it once I add it to my headerView.

Lastly, if I want to add a simple background gradient to my tableView, do I just set the `UITableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`, and have the backgroundView set to a gradient?  Cause that too does not seem to be working?  I only see the default colors of the grouped tableView.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably need to break this into separate questions. For the first, have you implemented `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with the header's height can be solved if you add the height in the tableview's designated method `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`.

For the color issue, I think you should set the background color of the cells to `clearColor` and then you should be able to get the desired effect.

Regarding the UILabel, the best way to get it centered is to make it the same width and height as the Header View and set it's `textAlignment` property to `UITextAlignmentCenter`.